# Show wordpress customize screen only for admins and moderators?

Tags: wordpress

When someone registers and login to my site wordpress redirects him to wp-admin area (*ok,i can fix this*), but registered users can see black screen, i don't like it.

You can see in picture below what i think, i want this only for admins and moderators:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With this code the adminbar is only active as an admin and an author:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'remove_admin_bar');

function remove_admin_bar() {
  if (!current_user_can('administrator') && !is_admin() $$ !is_author()) {
    show_admin_bar(false);
  }
}
```